# Magento 2 Filter Orders Based On shipping Country

Tags: magento2, orders, collection

I want to Filter Orders based on Shipping country I have filtered using other attributes like `grand_base_total` and `store_id` but struck at shipping country as there is no any attribute for that in `sales_order` table

Comment: Can you add your code for order collection ?So that I can add filter as per your requirement

Comment: I want to get only those order which has country_id = 'US

Comment: yes but can you add your collection query ?

Comment: @ParulThakkar I have done this please check my answer and let me know is it the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this using one of the clues from M1 Question

```
protected $_orderCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory
) {
    $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
}
public function getOrderCollection()
{
      $collection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()
            /* Joined with `sales_order_address` to get COuntry Id */
            ->join(
                'sales_order_address',
                'sales_order_address.parent_id=main_table.entity_id',
                'sales_order_address.country_id ')
            /* Added `country_id` Filter */
            ->addFieldToFilter('country_id', 
                array('IN' => 'US,UK')
            );
        return $collection;
}
```